# How to compute the exceptional divisor of this blow-up

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose that $k$ is a field and $R$ is the ring $k[x,xy,xy^2,xy^3]$.Let $I$ be the maximal ideal of $R$ generated by $x,xy,xy^2,xy^3$.Let $E$ be the exceptional divisor of the blow-up of Spec$R$ along the ideal $I$. How do I show that $E$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1_k$?
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: In fact, $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is the affine cone over a twisted rational cubic curve. Consequently, blowing up the origin you obtain the total space of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(-3)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ and the exceptional divisor is its zero section.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: @Sasha: Hello Sasha, could you please explain in more detail why the total space of the line bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1$ here is $O(-3)$ and that the exceptional divisor is its zero section? Thank you so much.